# Selecting best case value from every five minute segment

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset that looks like this (containing much more data):

| id | esn | ping_response | ping_response_time | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 753007 | 18067736 | 200 | 2204 | 2024-01-04 21:35:00 |
| 753008 | 18068072 | 200 | 2205 | 2024-01-04 21:35:00 |
| 753010 | 18068066 | 0 | 0 | 2024-01-04 21:35:00 |
| 752924 | 18002333 | 200 | 592 | 2024-01-04 21:25:00 |
| 752927 | 18002336 | 200 | 709 | 2024-01-04 21:25:00 |
| 752929 | 18002358 | 200 | 817 | 2024-01-04 21:25:00 |

What I want to do is get the best-case ping_response for each five minute interval. Ideally, this would be 200, but it could also be other values such as 400 or 0. However, if a value of 200 exists within the five minute interval, I want that instead.

I tried to build a query around the results of another query. The inner query is like so:

```
SELECT ping_response, time
FROM esn_ping
WHERE time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
ORDER BY time, CASE ping_response
  WHEN 200 THEN 0
  WHEN 400 THEN 1
  ELSE 2
END ASC
```

And that gave me a nice list of ordered values. I figured I could simply then group by time and everything would work as it would take the first result for each unique instance of time. However, as we know you cannot perform a GROUP BY immediately after an ORDER BY. No problem, I figured, I would simply wrap another query around this one, like so:

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
  SELECT ping_response, time
  FROM esn_ping
  WHERE time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
  ORDER BY time, CASE ping_response
    WHEN 200 THEN 0
    WHEN 400 THEN 1
    ELSE 2
  END ASC
) a GROUP BY time;
```

However, upon doing so, the order of the inner query is completely undone and I do not get the expected result for each interval. Considering the above data, I would expect '2024-01-04 21:35:00' to give me a value of 200, but instead I get a value of 0.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I correct this?

Comment: Can't you just use `MAX(ping_response) ... GROUP BY time`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "best case" means minimum?? (If so, then the "last" is not what you need.)

```
SELECT  MIN(time),          -- the bucket
        MIN(ping_response)  -- the 'best' ping
    FROM  esn_ping
    WHERE  ping_response != 0    -- avoid bogus values
    GROUP BY  FLOOR(TO_SECONDS(time) / 300)  -- 5 minute intervals
    ORDER BY 1    -- refers to MIN(time)
```